# How to add Default Value for a New Column in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm using dtsx in data migration between two SQL Server instance. One of the table changed the schema by adding a new text field which is not nullable. How can I add defualt value for the field or map it from another table? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy and quick fix to this would be to add a Derived Column component and simply add a new column to the dataflow with the default value you would like placed in that new column.